# Add numbering in Interactive Report of Pentaho User Console

Tags: pentaho

I have a query that show a list of item. I use that query to create a report using Interactive Report in Pentaho User Console. My problem is I don't know how to add numbering column in that report using Interactive Report application. Can anyone tell me is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to add the Serial No like 1,2,3.. with the list of items?

Comment: yup. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes.. have done it in Reports Designer in Pentaho. But looks like you are using Interactive Report so I am not sure about that. However I can tell you a way of doing it in the query, if you can manage with serial no from the query output itself.